# Maven command line configuration arguments not affecting build

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

**Question:**
How can I force Maven to apply VM options in the command line?

**Problem:**
Commands such as

```
mvn clean install -Dmaven.compiler.source=1.8 -Dmaven.compiler.target=1.8
mvn jetty:run -DuiFramework.development.<project-name>="<PathToProject>"
```

Are producing the same results, respectively, as the commands

```
mvn clean install
mvn jetty:run
```

**Bonus Question:**
Why are the VM options not currently being considered during the build?

Comment: Have you configured the plugin in the pom.xml as well?

Comment: @nullpointer I do not have the authority to configure the pom file. I should not need to, as intellij is able to make these changes successfully.

Answer (score 0):

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64 mvn clean install;
```

and

```
MAVEN_OPTS="-DuiFramework.development.<project-name>=<PathToProject>" mvn jetty:run
```

Turned out to be the commands I was looking for, respectivly.

This does not answer, however, why the `-D...` arguments did not work.

Comment: What do you mean by VM options? The -D defines a system property... And compiler.source simply indicates what version sources and compilation are made against, it is not used to find a suitable VM (unlike JAVA_HOME). As for the -DuiFramework, does your pathname or project name contains any special characters?

Comment: @asettouf VM options is what IntelliJ calls these options in its UI. The pathname and project name do not contain any special characters.

Answer (score 0):

Following `mvn --help`, options come *before* the goals, so you need to write

```
mvn -Dmaven.compiler.source=1.8 -Dmaven.compiler.target=1.8 clean install
```